# Why Elixir's nil implements Access behavior?

Tags: elixir

As Elixir [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html) say:

> ...Access transparently ignores nil values:

```
iex> keywords = [a: 1, b: 2]
iex> keywords[:c][:unknown]
nil
```

This seems error-prone to me. I'd rather see `nil[key]` failing than returning `nil`.

I'm pretty sure there's a good reason why the language developers chose to go this route. What is that reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nil` does not implements an `Access` behaviour (`nil` is an atom FWIW.)

What happens there is: `Access.fetch(nil, whatever)` returns `:error` and `get` [wraps `:error` to the default value](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.4.5/lib/elixir/lib/access.ex#L271) passed to `Access.get/3` as a third parameter.

The question “why” is better to address to José, the only idea I could come with is: that behaviour simplifies the code in case of deeply nested structures.

Also, this is a default behaviour for the first-level maps access:

```
iex> %{a: 42}[:b]
nil
```